# How to insert into one table from multiple table while using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

I have the following query which queries different table and uses the `UNION` operator to display a set of data:

```
-----TOTAL COUNT OF ACTIVE DEA----- DEA
select attr1671 as 'TYPE', count(attr1668) as 'TOTAL'

from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectinsta d inner join (select fk1665, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectinsta
group by fk1665) n on d.objectid = n.newobjectid where attr1671 = 'DEA' and cast(attr1668 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0
group by attr1671


-----TOTAL COUNT OF ACTIVE LICENSES----- LICENSE
UNION
select 'LICENSE' as 'TYPE', count(*) as 'TOTAL'

from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectin t inner join (select fk1656, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectin
group by fk1656) c on t.objectid = c.newobjectid where cast(attr1660 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0


-----TOTAL INFECTION CERTIFICATIONS ACTIVE----- INFECTION
UNION
select 'INFECTION' as 'TYPE', count(*) 'TOTAL'

from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobject z inner join (select fk1676, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobject
group by fk1676) h on z.objectid = h.newobjectid where cast(attr1680 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0



-----TOTAL COUNT OF ACTIVE CDS----- CDS
UNION
select attr1671 as 'TYPE', count(attr1668) as 'TOTAL'

from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobje k inner join (select fk1665, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobje
group by fk1665) l on k.objectid = l.newobjectid where attr1671 = 'CDS' and cast(attr1668 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0
group by attr1671
```

Which displays the following:

```
TYPE          TOTAL
CDS           45
DEA           56
INFECTION     67
LICENSE       41
```

I would like to insert the data into a table that I can import as a DataSet in my SSRS report. How can I achieve it?

I tried doing the following:

```
-----TOTAL COUNT OF ACTIVE DEA----- DEA
select attr1671 as 'TYPE', count(attr1668) as 'TOTAL'
INTO [MYDB].[DBO].[myT] --on first run and then comment
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectinsta d inner join (select fk1665, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectinsta
group by fk1665) n on d.objectid = n.newobjectid where attr1671 = 'DEA' and cast(attr1668 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0
group by attr1671


-----TOTAL COUNT OF ACTIVE LICENSES----- LICENSE
UNION
select 'LICENSE' as 'TYPE', count(*) as 'TOTAL'
INTO [MYDB].[DBO].[myT] --on first run and then comment
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectin t inner join (select fk1656, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobjectin
group by fk1656) c on t.objectid = c.newobjectid where cast(attr1660 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0


-----TOTAL INFECTION CERTIFICATIONS ACTIVE----- INFECTION
UNION
select 'INFECTION' as 'TYPE', count(*) 'TOTAL'
INTO [MYDB].[DBO].[myT] --on first run and then comment
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobject z inner join (select fk1676, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobject
group by fk1676) h on z.objectid = h.newobjectid where cast(attr1680 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0



-----TOTAL COUNT OF ACTIVE CDS----- CDS
UNION
select attr1671 as 'TYPE', count(attr1668) as 'TOTAL'
INTO [MYDB].[DBO].[myT] --on first run and then comment
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobje k inner join (select fk1665, max(objectid) 'newobjectid'
from [MyServer].[DBOTYPE].instance.rmobje
group by fk1665) l on k.objectid = l.newobjectid where attr1671 = 'CDS' and cast(attr1668 as date) > cast(getdate()+30 as date) and activestatus = 0
group by attr1671
```

But that didn't work. Please help...

This is the error I get:

`Msg 196, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
SELECT INTO must be the first query in a statement containing a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.`

Comment: what do you mean by `that does not work` ? what is the error/problem ?

Comment: The error I get is `Msg 196, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
SELECT INTO must be the first query in a statement containing a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping the whole thing as a subselect:

```
select *
into <whatever>
from (<your query here>
     ) t;
```

Comment: This work by the way... Just curious to know what the `t` is for.

Comment: @SiKni8 . . . `t` is a table alias and it is needed for subqueries in the `from` clause in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you. I have to wait for 6 mins before accepting your answer :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
With Emp_CTE (Employee,Count)
AS
(

   Select Firstname as Employee , Count(*) as Count from Employee
   where FirstName like 'V%'
   group by FirstName

   union 

   Select Firstname as Employee , Count(*) as Count from Employee
   where FirstName like 'M%'
   group by FirstName

)
Select * into dbo.EmployeeCount from Emp_CTE;
```